# How to loop picturebox going left inifnity

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm making a slideshow image and the direction of images is going left.

Now my problem is how can I make it an infinite loop? Once the last image appears, I want to show again the first image up to the last image again. How can I make this? Heres my code:

```
PictureBox[] clouds = new PictureBox[4];

public Form2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   speed = 3;
   clouds[0] = pictureBox1;
   clouds[1] = pictureBox2;
   clouds[2] = pictureBox3;
   clouds[3] = pictureBox4;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
   {
      clouds[x].Left -= 10;

      if (clouds[x].Left == 0)
      {
         clouds[x].Left = +this.Width;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use <= 0, not == 0, for the test; otherwise it will reset only if it hits zero exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ...
```

sequence. It can be implemented as

```
 // x = 0          - start with x = 0
 //                - no condition (infinte loop)
 // x = (x + 1) %4 - modulo arithemetics: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0 ....
 for (int x = 0; ; x = (x + 1) % 4) {
   ... 
 }
```

In general case for `clouds[]` array we can get rid of *magic number* `4`

```
 for (int x = 0; ; x = (x + 1) % array.Length) {
   ... 
 }
```