# How to move a picturebox around on a form so that when it reaches the end of the form it will loop back to the other side?

Tags: c#

I am already done with the left going right and it successfully returned to start position after reaching the end of the form  here's my code:

```
pictureBox1.Left +=10;

if (pictureBox1.Left >= this.Width )
{
    pictureBox1.Left = 0 - pictureBox1.Width; //Move the picturebox goes to start again

    ...                
}
```

Now my problem is, how can I do this if the PictureBox goes from right to left? I know the code I will just make the `pictureBox1.Left +=10` to `pictureBox1.Left -=10` but how can I make it start again on its starting position?

Comment: `if (pictureBox1.Left <= -pictureBox1.Width ) {pictureBox1.Left =  this.Width;};`

Answer (score 0):

You can try another `for` loop:

[How to loop picturebox going left inifnity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399733/how-to-loop-picturebox-going-left-inifnity/51399777#51399777)

Like this:

```
  // we start at pictureBox1.Left (which is initial position) with step = 10 
  // no condition (infinite loop)
  // move to the right 
  for (int left = pictureBox1.Left, initial = pictureBox1.Left, step = 10; ; left += step) {
    // If we beoynd [0 - step..Width + step] range, we
    //   1. Go to initial position
    //   2. Reverse direction 
    if (left >= Width + step && left <= -step) {
      left = initial;
      step = -step;
    }

    pictureBox1.Left = left;
  }
```